# How to resolve the package broken issue in Centos 6.2?

Tags: centos6, rpm

I have tried to upgrade php 5.3 to php 5.6 but it shows the below error.

```
 Error: Package: gd-last-2.2.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
                Requires: libwebp.so.5()(64bit)
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
     You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodiges
```

Followed the below steps.

If you haven’t already done so, install the Remi and EPEL repositories

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm && rpm -Uvh epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm



wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm && rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm
```

Enable the REMI repository globally:

```
nano /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
```

Under the section that looks like [remi] make the following changes:

```
[remi]
name=Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/remi/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/remi/mirror
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
```

Also, under the section that looks like [remi-php55] make the following changes:

```
[remi-php56]
name=Remi's PHP 5.6 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/php56/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/php56/mirror
# WARNING: If you enable this repository, you must also enable "remi"
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
```

Comment: Have you tried to execute `yum clean all` and try again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>            Requires: libwebp.so.5()(64bit)
> ```

This is provided by libwebp-0.4.3-3.el6.x86_64 in EPEL.
Check that you don't have another version from another 3rd party repository.

P.S. also notice than CentOS 6.2 is not maintained, 6.9 is current version.

Comment: I have upgraded my OS version.